# Чпу категории как поддомены

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Есть задача вывести категории и товары как поддомены.

```
Каталог site.ru/catalog/index.php -> catalog.site.ru

Разделы site.ru/catalog/index.php?&SECTION_CODE=cat1 -> cat1.site.ru

Товар site.ru/catalog/index.php?&SECTION_CODE=cat1&ELEMENT_CODE=prod1 -> prod1.cat1.site.ru
```

Помогите разобраться, делал таким образом: (Для товаров)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.site.ru
RewriteCond %{http_host} (www\.)?(.*)\.(.*)\.site\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catalog/item.php?ELEMENT_CODE=%2&SECTION_CODE=%3 [QSA,L]
```